Approaches to optimize "tight" code fragments in CUDA code
I am optimizing CUDA kernel that processes image and amount of work that is made for each source pixel changes during the process. For example, I have a 2D loop at some place, something like
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        sum += calc_value(x + i * alpha, y + j *beta, vec, something_else);

and less intensive fragments like
Vec3 vec = calc_vector(x, y, something_else_2);

The code is actually much more complicated and include outer loops and gathering of results from such 2D loops, but generally this is something like
__global__ process_pixel(Data data)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y;
    Vec3 results[8][10];

    for (int delta = 0; delta < 8; delta++)
        for (int stage = 0; stage < 10; stage++)
        {
            Vec3 vec = calc_vector(x, y, stage);
            Vec3 vec2 = calc_vector2(x, y, delta);
            float sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    sum += calc_value(x + i * alpha, y + j * beta, vec, vec2, delta, stage);
            results[delta][stage] = func(sum);
        }
    find_best(results);    // And so on
}

Indeed a lot of memory is used by each thread, actually much more than I have shown. And so there is a problem with lack of registers. And there are calculations that can be optimized because they do not depend from delta or from stage or from i, but this requires even more memory.
So I decided to regroup threads so each group of 5 threads worked in parallel on one pixel. Thus we could spread the required memory among them. So instead of e.g. 16 * 8 threads each processing one pixel I started to use 16 * 10 thread blocks and added additional outer loop by pixels, so when we enter for (int delta = 0; delta < 8; delta++) we are going to process only 16 * 2 pixels together. This gave some improvement in memory and compute GPU subsystems occupancy, but they are still far from optimal, like 40%. And another problem has arose is that I need to calculate some things with only part of threads or use a lot of shared memory:
    int tid = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;
    for (int delta = 0; delta < 8; delta++)
        for (int stage = 0; stage < 10; stage++)
        {
            __shared__ Vec3 vecs[block_size / 5];
            if (tid < block_size / 5)
                vecs[tid] = calc_vector(x, y, stage);
            __syncthreads();

            __shared__ float sums[block_size / 5];
            float sum = 0;
            int i = threadIdx.y;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                sum += calc_value(x + i * alpha, y + j *beta, vec, vec2, delta, stage);
            atomicAdd(&(sums[threadIdx.x]), sum);     // Another bad thing, but let us not discuss it now
            ...
       

Although generally the approach looks logical, it looks like this processing with only 32 threads out of 160 and __syncthreads() produces big performance bottleneck. At one code fragment I even got worse results with such approach in comparison to calculation of the same with all threads. I thought it would not be a problem that 128 threads are idle because we should have many other working thread blocks in parallel (I was able to get theoretical occupancy like 80%). But it looks like it is a problem (although I could make mistake during experiments and profiling) and also the assembly code gets a lot of shared stores and loads in comparison to "not optimized" code in which there are many FFMULs and that's all.
And then the fact arises that shared memory is even smaller than registers memory... If we do not take GF 4090, we have e.g. 96 KB. So if we want 2048 threads per SM we need to limit ourselves with 12 float values per thread. Even less than 32 registers...
So the question is which other approaches could be applied here? Something simple and effective... I see the following ways. Since we already have variant 1 - simply calculate everything by all threads and 2 - calculate with small subset of threads, this will be 3 and 4.

Use bigger shared memory buffer and precalculate things with all threads, so
     __shared__ Vec3 vecs[5][block_size / 5];
     for (int stage = 0; stage < 10; stage++)
     {
         if (stage == 0 || stage == 5)
         {
             vecs[...][...] = calc_vector...
             __syncthreads();
         } ...


Try hard to parallelize calc_vector too like we did above with for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++), to spread results in local variables and then exchange them among neighbor threads with __shfl_up_sync and so on. Looks too monstrous.


Any other ideas?

On recent devices where 2048 threads can be resident on each SM (which are only the big server accelerators), there is 164KB (SM 8.0) or 228KB (SM 9.0) of shared memory per SM (minus some small amount that is inaccessible to blocks). But you need to use dynamic shared memory to make use of it. On all other recent devices (SM 8.6, 8.7 and 8.9) like the RTX 4090, only 1536 threads can be resident on each SM. With static shared memory you only get 48KB independent of architecture.

If a single kernel gets that complicated and its level parallelization changes that much, I'd take it as a sign that maybe the whole operation should be split into smaller kernels that individually can be made more efficient. Alternatively, you could split a thread block into multiple cooperative groups and set up a producer-consumer pipeline to keep all threads busy with different stages of the computation

@Homer512, I would say if a kernel becomes too complicated, this is because developers are going to optimize the code seriously. It already has problem with global RAM access latency (although bandwidth which is used is relatively low) so division would make this worser and kill performance fully.
I read a bit about producer-consumer (on GPU), but still not sure whether this is real approach. They used assembly inlines to use named barriers. And cooperative groups seemed to me too complicated... Did you implement such thing?

If you are worried about the additional memory requirements of splitting the kernel, try two things, as appropriate: 1. Split the whole work set into smaller blocks so that temporary results and repeated loads fit into L2 cache. 2. Consider when it is cheaper to recompute values rather than load them from memory. Keep in mind that high end GPUs can do well over 100 floating point operations for every cache-cold memory load.

@Homer512, Oh, if we divide, I'm afraid most calculations there are cheaper to recompute. Also intermediate values are much more numerous, than source data, maybe 10x. Most FLOPs are inside depicted delta and stage loops, so it looks very unnatural to divide the logic inside. 2. In the current state it looks like the price of calculations is near the price of storing-loading to shared memory, so I am searching for alternatives since we have quite a lot of other variant

Here is a simple producer-consumer pipeline that splits off some warps to do different work without having any of them go idle but it needs tuning to get the thread distribution right and consumes shared memory: https://pastebin.com/MF8gw9Zr

@Homer512, Ha! I see :) So this way we increase parallelism, e.g. instead of 4 consumer warps we can get 4+1 or 4+2 working warps... But shared memory consumption increase 2x. I will think again where I could apply this... Yes, I have one code part where I can prepare some data in parallel with processing of previous portion of such data... And we get 1 syncthreads instead of 2 with such approach. Thank you!
